# issues after verbatim section

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking, verbatim, typewriter

I'm havin an issue which I cannot solve. If I have a subsubsection containing text with a `verbatim` section in between, the first line after the `verbatim` section is not aligned properly. If I put a `\newline` command after the verbatim, everything works, but it shows the error

```
There's no line here to end
```

This is the code:

```
\subsubsection{Umsetzung}
    C: \texttt{if(r1 > r2)$\{$statement;$\}$} \newline
    Realisierung in 2 Schritten: zuerst die Register vergleichen, dann auf Grund
    von Flags bedingten Sprung ausführen.
    \begin{verbatim}
        cp r1, r2   ; vergleiche (compare) r1 mit r1
        brge L1     ; verzweige falls r1 >= r2 (mit Vorzeichen!)
        ...
        statement
        ...
        L1: nop         ; hier geht es weiter
    \end{verbatim}

    C: \texttt{if(r1 > r2)$\{$statement1;$\}$else$\{$statement2;$\}$} \newline
    Assembler:
    \begin{verbatim}
        cp r1, r2   ; vergleiche (compare) r1 mit r
        brge L1     ; verzweige falls r1 >= r2
        ...
        statement1
        ...
        rjmp L2
        L1: ...
        statement2
        ...
        L2: ...      ; hier geht es weiter
    \end{verbatim}
```

And this is the output:

[image]

Even if I remove the whole verbatim section, the described line stays on a new line and not properly aligned (and this - in my oppinion - is far stranger, shouldn't it just float at the end of the previous sentence since I never tell to break a line?).

[image]

Note that I slightly formatted the content of the `verbatim` sections here for better legibility, so don't be suprised if the alignment of the Assembler-code isn't like in the picture in case you compile my code.

Comment: It isn't clear what error you see. C is starting a new paragraph and so gets parindent. Perhaps you want to set parindent to 0pt, or use `\noindent` ? Or just omit the blank line which is causing the new paragraph if you do not want a paragraph break at that point.

Comment: Instead of the mixed modes `\texttt` and `$...$`, use `\verb|...|`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try one of three things:

- remove the empty line before the line you don't want indented
- put `\noindent` before your new line, or
- put `\hspace*{\fill}\newline`

The way your MWE is written, you've told LaTeX that you're staring a new paragraph.  If that's what you really want to do then the indentation is technically correct.  If you don't want paragraphs indented or you don't want just this paragraph indented, then you can use `\noindent`.  (Incidentally, LaTeX doesn't automatically indent the first paragraph after a section header.)

`\newline` doesn't like to end empty lines: hence the `\hspace*{\fill}` before it.  I would recommend not using `\newline` because you're creating even more white space.

Comment: obviously it was the indentation. I was so deadlocked in searching the reason in some fancy error, that I did not considered this. Thank you!